# MemoryLeak in onBackPressed with Animation

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I've created a rather complex end animation within an open source application.

If the onBackPressed() method is called the application will animate the views and close. it seems that there is a memory leek, because it won't stop to allocate new ram afterwards. If i remove the animation and just call a normal onBackPressed i don't have the mentioned behavior.

Here's the code i call in the onBackPressed method:

```
//make global var :D
ViewPropertyAnimator hideFabAnimator;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mFabDownloadButton.animate()
            .translationX(0)
            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MEDIUM)
            .start();

    //move the share fab below the normal fab (58 because this is the margin top + the half
    mFabShareButton.animate()
            .translationX(0)
            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MEDIUM)
            .setListener(new CustomAnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    //create the fab animation and hide fabProgress animation, set an delay so those will hide after the shareFab is below the main fab
                    hideFabAnimator = Utils.hideViewByScaleXY(mFabButton)
                            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MEDIUM);

                    Utils.hideViewByScaleXY(mFabDownloadButton)
                            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MEDIUM)
                            .start();
                    Utils.hideViewByScaleXY(mFabShareButton)
                            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MEDIUM)
                            .start();
                    Utils.hideViewByScaleXY(mFabProgress)
                            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MEDIUM)
                            .start();


                    //add listener so we can react after the animation is finished
                    hideFabAnimator.setListener(new CustomAnimatorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            try {
                                ViewPropertyAnimator hideFabAnimator = Utils.hideViewByScaleY(mTitleContainer);
                                hideFabAnimator.setListener(new CustomAnimatorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                        coolBack()
                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                coolBack()
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    hideFabAnimator.start();
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                }
            })
            .start();
}

/**
 *
 */
private void coolBack() {
    try {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

You can find the same source @github here: https://github.com/mikepenz/wall-splash-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/unsplash/activities/DetailActivity.java#L701

I tried already a lot of different stuff. but nothing helped.

Thanks.

Comment: try removing super.onBackPressed().. use finish() on animation end

Comment: oh sorry. did totally miss this line. was one of the things i tried. wait i update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i was able to solve this issue. It seems that if you use normal animations without a animationListener it can happen (it will happen) that the animation can't finish and will remain "in-tact". So it seems that it still processes something in the background, even if the activity is already closed.

So i was able to work around this issue by defining a listener-"chain" and check that all my animations finish.

Here's the code which works:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mFabDownloadButton.animate()
            .translationX(0)
            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MEDIUM)
            .setListener(animationFinishListener1)
            .start();


    //move the share fab below the normal fab (58 because this is the margin top + the half
    mFabShareButton.animate()
            .translationX(0)
            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MEDIUM)
            .setListener(animationFinishListener1)
            .start();
}

private CustomAnimatorListener animationFinishListener1 = new CustomAnimatorListener() {
    private int animateFinish1 = 0;

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        process();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationCancel(animation);
        process();
    }

    private void process() {
        animateFinish1 = animateFinish1 + 1;
        if (animateFinish1 == 2) {
            //create the fab animation and hide fabProgress animation, set an delay so those will hide after the shareFab is below the main fab
            Utils.hideViewByScaleXY(mFabDownloadButton)
                    .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MEDIUM)
                    .setListener(animationFinishListener2)
                    .start();
            Utils.hideViewByScaleXY(mFabShareButton)
                    .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MEDIUM)
                    .setListener(animationFinishListener2)
                    .start();
            Utils.hideViewByScaleXY(mFabProgress)
                    .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MEDIUM)
                    .setListener(animationFinishListener2)
                    .start();
            Utils.hideViewByScaleXY(mFabButton)
                    .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MEDIUM)
                    .setListener(animationFinishListener2)
                    .start();
        }
    }
};

private CustomAnimatorListener animationFinishListener2 = new CustomAnimatorListener() {
    private int animateFinish2 = 0;

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        process();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationCancel(animation);
        process();
    }

    private void process() {
        animateFinish2 = animateFinish2 + 1;
        if (animateFinish2 == 4) {
            ViewPropertyAnimator hideFabAnimator = Utils.hideViewByScaleY(mTitleContainer);
            hideFabAnimator.setListener(new CustomAnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    coolBack();
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

/**
 *
 */
private void coolBack() {
    try {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ew;
    }
}
```

So i keep a count of my animations, and will only go to the next animation if the first "batch" of animations is finished, and after that i will continue with the second "batch" of animations. As soon as those have finished i'll finish the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilar leak with animations. In my case I used

```
scaleY.setRepeatCount(1);
scaleY.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
```

for setRepeatCount I used INFINITY before, which also never endet the animation, even not after call explicit cancle() or end(). I just changed it to 1 (its not infinit anymore but I can live with it).
Just added this answer incase someone run into this as well.